# Controlling a USB device through a web service

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, usb

I am new to IoT development and a moderate user of C#.

The business ask I have is to install a programmable light on a machine and expose a local restful web service to flip on the light in the event of an issue.  I have a USB light (from Kuando) with a SDK that I have written a simple test interface dll using. It can claim the device, invoke various blinking patterns, and release the device.  When implemented into a windows form project this works like a champ.  However, trying to include this dll in a web service project is not going so well.

When attempting to instantiate the object and claim the device, I get an error stating "System event notifications are not supported under the current context".  I assume this is an underlying security issue with allowing web services to control machine hardware, however, that's exactly what I need to do in this case.

I'm looking for any architecture ideas or concepts that may be out there to help me get around this.  Or perhaps I'm a total idiot and missing something easy? Appreciate any help. Peace & humptiness forever.

Comment: Are you running your web service in IIS?

Comment: Yes, yes I am..

Comment: That may be the issue. Is it possible for you to run with Kestrel as your host and then run your service from the command line? At least as a test to verify whether that helps.

Comment: It appears you are correct.  IIS is not a fan of me manipulating the hardware layer.  Waaah!